# Difference between how physicists do statistics and how stats people do statistics?

Tags: experimental-physics, statistics

I am a physics student studying machine learning / data science, so I don't mean for this question to start any conflicts :) However, a big part of any physics undergraduate program is to do labs/experiments, which means a lot of data processing and statistical analysis. However, I notice a sharp difference between the way physicists deal with data and the way my data science / statistical learning books deal with data.

The key difference is that when trying to perform regressions to data obtained from physics experiments, the regression algorithms are applied to the WHOLE dataset, there is absolutely no splitting into training and test sets. In the physics world, the R^2 or some type of pseudo-R^2 is calculated for the model based on the whole data set. In the stats world, the data is almost always split up into 80-20, 70-30, etc... and then the model is evaluated against the test dataset.

There are also some major physics experiments (ATLAS, BICEP2, etc...) that never do this data splitting, so I'm wondering why there is a such a staunch difference between the way physicists/experimentalists do statistics and the way data scientists do statistics.

Thanks.

Thomas

Comment: I think splitting into training and test sets is more of a machine learning approach and is not as common in traditional statistical analysis.

Answer (score 2):

In physics most often we do have a model or a theory against which we test the data. Hence, we are interested in the *significance level* of the data and how well the data is described by theory.

In contrast, machine learning does not contain such an underlying theory. All it does is categorizing the data into groups. In order to evaluate the quality of the categorization, we have to cross-check it using new data.

Above I emphasized the difference between these two subjects (physics vs. machine learning). I guess one could also emphasize the similarity by taking the machine learning view. For a "machine learner" physics can be described as follows:

- The physicist generates data from a measurement. This corresponds to the *training dataset*.
- From this they generate a model / theory.
- Finally, they perform another experiment  (higher resolution, in a different parameter range, ...) in order to cross-check the model / theory. This corresponds to the *test dataset*.

In my opinion this interpretation is somehow coming short, because the main focus of physicists is to find new effects -- most papers at least claim this. For a "machine learner" this is *not* important. Maybe this corresponds to extrapolation of the model. However, that should be answered by a machine learner not a physicists.

Answer (score 0):

Your assessment is not universally true. For example, in protein crystallography, typically, a maximum likelihood fit of an atomic model is done keeping a fraction of the data out of the objective function, as a mean to assess the progress of the fit. A technique known as $R_\text{free}$.

Comment: Hi. It's not universally true, but, it is certainly true in the majority, at least from what I've seen in cosmology, particle physics, and the vast majority of undergraduate physics labs! :)

Comment: The issue might be the scarcity of data. Protein crystallography is a case in point: of the order of 100,000 for small ones to closer to a million diffraction peaks are measured, so they can afford to keep a fraction of the data out of the fit. Particle physics is most of the time the exact opposite: we are interested in very rare processes with a paucity of events and we can't afford to discard any of them.